# How to map Ctrl-p to up arrow using xmodmap?

Tags: linux

I did read the grammar section of xmodmap but still couldn't figure out how I could do it.

Comment: May be there is a way to map Ctrl-p/Ctrl-n to behave as up/down keys directly from gnome. Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't easily possible.

As the [xmodmap man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap) states:

```
The first keysym is used when no modifier key is pressed in conjunction with
this key, the second with Shift, the third when the Mode_switch key is used
with this key and the fourth when both the Mode_switch and Shift keys are used.
```

By default, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is the Mode_switch key.

It is possible to map a different or additional (to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) as the <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> key, e.g. the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Mode_switch Mode_switch"
```

The problem however is that the key then won't work as normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key anymore.

Btw: There is a question, which asks for precisely, how to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key as a modifier key:
[How to use Control as modifier with xmodmap?](https://superuser.com/questions/443050/how-to-use-control-as-modifier-with-xmodmap)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 33 = p P Up"
```

and let me know if it's the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As nidi said, that isn't easily possible with xmodmap.
However it's super easy with AutoKey.
See the following answer as an example: https://askubuntu.com/a/303978/140789