# How to use Control as modifier with xmodmap?

Tags: linux, key-binding, xmodmap

So I'm trying to create a combination of keys to generate ISO keys for the Portuguese layout, the key in question is the <kbd>< ></kbd>, pressing it will normally generate the `<` character, <kbd>< ></kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> will generate the `>` character. So I'm trying to create a combination using `xmodmap`, and I want this to work for all the programs. I've been searching on Google and came up with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/248161/how-to-map-ctrl-p-to-up-arrow-using-xmodmap) example for <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> = <kbd>Up</kbd>:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 33 = p P Up"
```

`keycode 33` matches <kbd>p</kbd>, so where does <kbd>Control</kbd> come up in that command?

What I want is:

- map <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to <kbd>></kbd>
- map <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to <kbd><</kbd>

Comment: So yeah the control modifier isnt working...anyway what the position for the control?

Comment: It's possible that the author removed his own answer because it wasn't correct.

Comment: ok. So this isnt possible with the xmodmap?

Answer (score 2):

The example from the other question is wrong.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 33 = p P Up"
```

normally means that pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> will result in <kbd>Up</kbd>.

More precisely it means that pressing
<kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> will result in <kbd>Up</kbd>.

As the [xmodmap man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap) states:

```
The first keysym is used when no modifier key is pressed in conjunction with
this key, the second with Shift, the third when the Mode_switch key is used
with this key and the fourth when both the Mode_switch and Shift keys are used.
```

It is possible to map different or additional (to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) as the <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> key, e.g. the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Mode_switch Mode_switch"
```

The problem however is that the key then won't work as normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key anymore.